can't retrive all the data from the access database in table view (Java FX 8
EmpView.setOnAction(event -> {
               ObservableList<Employee>data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                TableView<Employee>empTableView = new TableView<>();
                VBox emptableContainer = new VBox(empTableView);
                // Clear any previous data in the table
                //data.clear();
                    try {
                // Query the database to retrieve data from tblApartment
                String query = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee";
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
                
                while (resultSet.next()) {               
                    String eid = resultSet.getString("eid");
                     System.out.println("Employee Id: " + resultSet.getString("eid"));
                    String eName = resultSet.getString("eName");
                     System.out.println("Employee Name: " + resultSet.getString("eName"));
                    String dept = resultSet.getString("dept");
                    System.out.println("department: " + resultSet.getString("dept"));
                    String tel = resultSet.getString("tel");
                    System.out.println("Tel: " + resultSet.getString("tel"));
                    String email = resultSet.getString("email");
                    System.out.println("Email: " + resultSet.getString("email"));
                    boolean status = resultSet.getBoolean("status");
                    System.out.println("Status: " + String.valueOf(status));

                    Employee employee = new Employee(eid, eName, dept, tel, email, status);
                    System.out.println(employee.getEmpId());
                    System.out.println(employee.getEmpName());
                    System.out.println(employee.getDept());
                    System.out.println(employee.getContactNo());
                    System.out.println(employee.getEmail());
                    
                    data.add(employee);
                    
                    //data.add(new Apartment(resultSet.getString("apartmntId"),resultSet.getString("location"),resultSet.getInt("rental"),resultSet.getInt("numofTenant"),resultSet.getBoolean("vacant")));
                }
TableColumn<Employee, String>eidColumn = new TableColumn<>("Employee ID");
             eidColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("eid"));
             eidColumn.setMinWidth(150);
             
            TableColumn<Employee, String>eNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Employee Name");
            eNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("eName"));
            eNameColumn.setMinWidth(150);
            
            TableColumn<Employee, String>deptColumn = new TableColumn<>("Department");
            deptColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dept"));  
        deptColumn.setMinWidth(150);
        
            TableColumn<Employee, String>telColumn = new TableColumn<>("Tel");
            telColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tel"));
            telColumn.setMinWidth(150);
            
            TableColumn<Employee, String>emailColumn = new TableColumn<>("Email");
            emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));
            emailColumn.setMinWidth(150);
            
            TableColumn<Employee, Boolean>statusColumn = new TableColumn<>("Status");
            statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("status"));
            statusColumn.setMinWidth(150);
           empTableView.getColumns().addAll(eidColumn, eNameColumn, deptColumn, telColumn, emailColumn, statusColumn);
                // Set the data as the items for the TableView
            empTableView.setItems(data);
            
            // Add the VBox to the layout (assuming paneMain is your BorderPane)
            paneMain.setCenter(emptableContainer);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }             
        });


I'm using access database to save the data. When I do the error checking, all data can get from the Employee class, but when I click to view in table, only can get dept and email from the database.
I also checked the database eid,eName,dept, tel, email, and status are same as the database table(tblEmployee).
How to retrieve all the data from the database(tblEmployee) and display in table view
